# Does it matter where a contained object is created for it to be considered Composition or Aggregation?

Tags: java, oop

Examples first and then clarification after. This is my first post and I did try searching.

Example 1: Engine object created in Car constructor.

```
public class Car{

    private Engine engine;

    Car(){
        engine = new Engine();
    }
}
```

Example 2: Engine object created outside Car class and passed in through Car constructor.

```
public class Car{

    private Engine engine;

    Car(Engine engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

Example 3: Engine object created outside Car class and passed in through Car setEngine(Engine engine) method.

```
public class Car{

    private Engine engine;

    Car(){}

    public void setEngine(Engine engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

I think containment is both composition and aggregation and the contained object has an owner, like Car owns Engine. The difference I think is the life cycles of each object and when they are destroyed.

Composition: Engine Object destroyed when Car Object is destroyed.

Aggregation: Engine Object survives when Car Object is destroyed.

My googling and stackoverflow searches create ambiguity.

What examples from 1, 2, and 3 above are composition, aggregation, or both? And why? What examples above are an association relationship?

Comment: An aggregation would be a car with two engines. Like a Prius.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit

Comment: Example 2 looks like a [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It could model fuel injected vs carbureted; 4 cylinder vs 6 cylinder vs 8 cylinder; etc.

Comment: Did you forget your question?

Answer (score 0):

In #1 there is no ambiguity, that is composition since the engine can't live by it's own.

With #2 and #3 it could be one or the other, depending how you conceptually treat the engine. If the engine has it's own lifecycle (e.g. it could be removed from one car and installed in another car) then it's aggregation. Otherwise it's composition.

It's usually easier to reason about a model when objects are **clustered together only when they have the same lifecycle**.